# Unable to see wagtail's Generate Url

Tags: wagtail

I'm using Django 1.10.5 with Wagtail 1.8.  I just noticed there's no
'generate url' in the Images section.  Was it removed?

And, when I go to create a new entry, there aren't any 'justification'
buttons in the edit.  Were those removed, also?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those features have been removed from Wagtail. The 'generate URL' link is an optional feature which can be enabled as described here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/advanced_topics/images/image_serve_view.html

The only thing I can think of in Wagtail that could be described as a 'justification' button is the set of options for choosing image format (which default to left, right and full-width). This is still present in Wagtail (although note that it only appears when inserting an image into a rich text area, not when the image is an individual field). The Wagtail editing interface intentionally doesn't provide text justification options, because page layout is more correctly handled in the template, rather than inside page content.